# Resetting range with Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to delete the un-needed columns and rows in a range

I keep getting the error `Sorry, it is not possible to delete all non-frozen rows.` but only intermittently

Never on columns only the rows

I have the header row frozen

I can not figure out why I check to make sure I am not deleting all the rows with `if (maxRows-lastRow > 0 && maxRows > 1)`

Any help please, this is frustrating

Thanks

```
function ResetRange(arrShtNames) {
  var allsheets = arrShtNames;
  for (var s in allsheets){
    var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(allsheets[s]);

    var maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns(); 
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    if (maxColumns-lastColumn > 0 && maxColumns > 1){
      sheet.deleteColumns(lastColumn+1, maxColumns-lastColumn);
    };

    if (maxRows-lastRow > 0 && maxRows > 1){
      sheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, maxRows-lastRow);
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

My top row and my left column are frozen.

```
function resetRange(nA){
  //var namesA=['myPage'];
  var namesA=nA;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  if(namesA){
    for(var i=0;i<namesA.length;i++){
      var sh=ss.getSheetByName(namesA[i]);
      if(sh.getMaxColumns()>sh.getLastColumn()){
        sh.deleteColumns(sh.getLastColumn()+1,sh.getMaxColumns()-sh.getLastColumn());
      }
      if(sh.getMaxRows()>sh.getLastRow()){
        sh.deleteRows(sh.getLastRow()+1, sh.getMaxRows()-sh.getLastRow());
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Frozen rows or columns don't seem to matter in my situation.  Perhaps your situation is different.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try